# increase counter each time i call a function within a class

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a class which has many plotting functions. My intention is to group all plots in one image with the subplot method of matplotlib, depending on how many functions I call.

I tried something like the following (which is a short version of my program), but i don't know why is not working.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, a, multiPlot=True, numColGraph=None, numRowGraph=None,
                 figSize=None, DPI=None, num=None):

        self.a = a
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 5)

        if multiPlot:
        self.nCG = numColGraph
            self.nRG = numRowGraph
        else:
            self.nCG = 1
            self.nRG = 1

        if figSize and DPI:
            self.thePlot = plt.figure(figsize=figSize, dpi=DPI)

        if num == 0:
            self.plotId = itertools.count(1)

    def createPlot1(self):
        y = self.x**(a/2)
        self.thePlot.add_subplot(self.nRG, self.nCG, next(self.plotId))
        plt.plot(self.x, y, label=str(self.a)+'/2')

    def createPlot2(self):
        y = self.x**a
        self.thePlot.add_subplot(self.nRG, self.nCG, next(self.plotId))
        plt.plot(self.x, y, label=self.a)

    def createPlot3(self):
        y = self.x**(2*a)
        self.thePlot.add_subplot(self.nRG, self.nCG, next(self.plotId))
        plt.plot(self.x, y, label=str(self.a)+'*2')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    A = np.linspace(0, 2, 5)

    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        Instance = Base(a, numColGraph=3, numRowGraph=len(A),
                 figSize=(12,10), DPI=100, num=i)
        Instance.createPlot1()
        Instance.createPlot2()
        Instance.createPlot3()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: When you say "it's not working", can you be more specific about what you expect to work and what instead happens?

Comment: Well, to start with, I get the following error: 'Base' object has no attribute 'plotId' but I have decleared it. I want to get, after looping, the three plots in the same figure (graph, o whatever you call it). The problem I have is increasing the plotId variable each time I call a function. Sorry if I don't make my self clear, english is not my native language.

Comment: I suspect you may be using your `plotId` variable incorrectly.

It only gets set `if num == 0`, but you're instantiating `Base` objects with 0 once (from enumerate) and not again.

Comment: The edited version still raises syntax errors—possibly just because of the indentation error after `if multiPlot:`, but rather than making us guess at what you're intending, it would be better if you gave us actual code that runs (up to the point where it demonstrates the problem you want solved, of course).

Answer (score 1):

At a bare minimum, you have undefined variables. I see this pattern (or something like it) three times:

```
y = self.x**(2*a)
```

But in none of those cases have you defined `a`. Perhaps you mean:

```
y = self.x**(2*self.a)
```

Comment: Yes, sorry i ended pasting the unfinished example. Sorry for that. I corrected.

Comment: @ezitoc There are still errors as noted by cwallenpoole in your question.